# Empty bpy.data.node_groups

Tags: python

I need to change the value of an RGB node programmatically. The data path of the node in question is `bpy.data.node_groups["Compositing Nodetree"].nodes["RGB"]`, as can be seen in the screenshot attached.

[image: Empty bpy.data.node_groups]

However, if I enter that path into the Python console, no node groups are returned. I.e. `bpy.data.node_groups.keys()` is empty.

What is going on here? How can one access node groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the *compositing* node tree via:

```
bpy.context.scene.node_tree
```

And your RGB node this way:

```
bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes['RGB']
```

As for why the tooltip shows a data path that you can't really access?

Don't really know, might be a **bug**.

Comment: That did the trick, thank you! The data path displayed in blender is definitely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a different fix:

1. I created the material with `<MATERIAL> = bpy.data.materials.new`
2. Attached the material to the object with `C.object.data.materials.append`
3. Set `<MATERIAL>.use_nodes = True`

And the path suggested by Blender to edit, e.g., specular intensity was misleading: It suggested `bpy.data.node_groups["Shader Nodetree"].nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[5].default_value` but `node_groups`was an empty collection.

**I could access the value in the node tree with the following path:**

```
<MATERIAL>.node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF'].inputs[5].default_value = 0
```

Hope this helps someone!
Cheers,
Andres

Comment: Certainly helped me. I've successfully used:     
    mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name='orange')
    mat.use_nodes = True
   mat.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs[0].default_value = (1.0,0.5,0.0,1.0)

Comment: Glad to hear that! the node system rocks